# Calling same service multiple times, sign of bad design?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm in the process of building out a fairly large Angular app and I've stuck to the design of building 'thin' controllers. My controllers don't try to do too much, they are each focused on one piece of functionality within my app.

There, however, is certain data that is 'shared' between controllers. I aim to avoid using `$rootScope` and instead rely on services to share data and 'state'.

When looking in the 'Network' tab of Chrome Dev Tools I notice certain services being called half a dozen times. So my question is, is this bad design? Are multiple calls to the same service within an Angular app not the 'Angular way' to do things? Note: these service calls take ~ 20ms each, so clearly not much of a performance hit...so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest reducing the number of unnecessary HTTP requests that you're making for two reasons:

1. In production environments, these HTTP requests may take more time to complete when factors such as network latency or server load are taken into account; and
2. will delay the loading of any other assets such as images (assuming that they're coming from the same domain).

An approach that I've used when dealing with the scenario that you've described is to cache the response/data from the API in the service. So, on subsequent calls to the service, the data can be pulled from the cache rather than the API.

See a brief example below:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) {

  var posts = [];

  var service = {
    all: all
  }

  return service;

  function all() {
    // if cached posts exist, return those. Otherwise, make call to external API.
    if (posts.length > 0) {
      return posts.$promise;
    } else {
      posts = $resource('http://localhost/api/v1/posts.json').query();
      return posts.$promise;
    }
  }

}]);
```

Note: you'll also have to consider resetting your cache however this would be dependent on your application logic.

Hope this helps!

L

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should look to use [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) to reduce service calls.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about REST services? Are you making $http calls in order to share data and state between controllers?

Why not use [service/factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) in Angular?

Comment: I'm talking about Angular services which call to my REST API endpoints. Several of my controllers call the same Angular service and I'm wondering if this is an efficient way to handle things.

Comment: Are we talking about $http GET? If the data is static (like a list of countries) you can use the "cache: true" inside the $http GET call. Please provide more info about what you are trying to accomplish :) **Edit:** services/factories/providers are the singletons of Angular. In terms of best practice, what you are doing is "technically" ok. I just think that with more provided info maybe there's a better solution to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm performing CRUD operations, so GET, PUT, POST, DELETE. The data changes fairly frequently, definitely not static lists.

Comment: I understood that, but you originally wrote that you want to share data between controllers. Please provide a more specific use case/example/code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is
1. DataCache service/factory - which will store your response from server
2. A directive - to call these services. include it in your different views
3. Now inside your service which is responsible for making http call first check if data is available in cache if yes return promise of stored data (you can use $q.when) if not make service call.

> I have mentioned point 2 since I am assuming inside your various controller you must be doing something like AbcFactory.getItem().then() to avoid duplication of this code as you never know when the requirement will change since change is the only constant during development ;)